# Official Cardona Telegram Channel?

Tags: security

Is this an official Cardano Telegram channel?

https://t.me/Cardonacommunitychat

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question on technology or systems using cardano.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

No that is a scam! No one is ever going to "return ada to your wallet". There will never be an ada giveaway from IOG or Charles Hoskinson.

Comment: Thank you. I imagined this to be the issue. It should be taken down and reported.

Answer (score 2):

I have reported this Telegram Channel. This was an important security question in my opinion